# waypoints pass a custom variable

Tags: google-maps

I need to pass a custom variable through `loadFromWaypoints` so that i can later use that variable in the `GEvent.addListener`. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a createDelegate to manage your arguments.  And "arguments" is also an unspoken variable to access the function's arguments, even though you didn't assign a parameter to it.

[Create Delegate](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Ext.html#method-Function-createDelegate)

Although this is in the Sencha.EXTJS framework, most frameworks have a similar method.

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", myMethod.createDelegate(map, marker, true));
```

marker will be appended to the list of parameters.  I hope this gives you some ideas as to how this might work.